# inner class able to access outer classes attributes from method only

Tags: java, inner-classes

Please review this code which compiles fine :

```
class OuterClass {

    String a = "A";
    String b = "B";
    String c = "C";


    public static class StaticInnerClass {

    }

    public String stringConCat() {
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

this is as  i expect as the inner class can access the outer classes attributes. But now when i try the same code but assigning a outer attribute to inner attribute the system complains:

```
class OuterClass {

    String a = "A";
    String b = "B";
    String c = "C";


    public static class StaticInnerClass {
        String x = a; //this can not be done, why ?
    }

    public String stringConCat() {
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

the error/warning at compile time is: Non-static field `a` cannot be referenced from a static context.

is it because in the method `stringConCat()` you actually need an instance to call the method (post constructor call) so its allowed ? Whereas, in the second example there is no real instance so it treats it as a static reference ?

I've read [I thought inner classes could access the outer class variables/methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251922/i-thought-inner-classes-could-access-the-outer-class-variables-methods) but its still not sinking. Can someone help?

Comment: There is no inner class here. 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms. What you have here is a static *nested* class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in your error message: "Non-static field a cannot be referenced from a static context."

inner classes *can* access outer class variables, but your nested class is static, not inner, and the variable is not static. Either make the variable static, or make the nested class non-static.

Comment: oh i get what your saying now Chris good point.  My class is static and im trying to access a non-static value which is not permitted and makes no sense as outer class can have many instances and it would not know which "a" to give me.  Not sure why i got a downvote from someone for asking lol .Thanks a bunch.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms. This is a static nested class.